# Trying to update data with guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

I am using Guzzle and I need to update data, so for this I am trying the following:

```
$request = $this->guzzleClient->put($this->url, [
    'headers' => $this->dcsheaders,
    'json' =>  json_encode([
        "status" => "Open",
        "accountNumber"=> "01236548",
        "reasonId"=>"ccaa8e8d-70ae-466d-b8c8-dd16bc5454e0"
    ])
]);

$a = $request->send();
var_dump($a);
```

But I receive

> resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response

I tried another types like form_params, but I receive 403

Comment: What kind of auth the endpoit use?

Comment: I am sending the following headers

 'content-type' => 'application/json',
'X-Api-Key' => PROXY_API_KEY

Comment: remove json_encode if you are using json request param it is like doing json_encode over json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The json option is used to easily upload JSON encoded data as the body of a request.

**source**: [json request option guzzle](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#json)

change to this

```
$request = $this->guzzleClient->put($this->url, [
    'headers' => $this->dcsheaders,
    'json' =>  [
            "status" => "Open",
            "accountNumber"=> "01236548",
            "reasonId"=>"ccaa8e8d-70ae-466d-b8c8-dd16bc5454e0"
          ]
]);
```